# Reusing simple Javascript Function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS and would like to know how to refactor this simple code so that I can pass in strings to count the number of "e" in a string.

```
function countE() {
  var count = 0;
  var str = "eee";
  var charLength = str.length;

  for (i =0; i <= charLength; i++){
      if(str.charAt(i) == "e"){
          count++;
      }
  }
   console.log(count);
}
```

I would like to execute this function where I can do something like this:

```
countE('excellent elephants');
```

which would log  5.

Comment: Are you asking how can you pass arguments to a function?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: I also would like to know how to have this function execute without having to call it .. ex. countE(); unless I want to pass in a different arg.

Comment: `function countE(str)`

Comment: if you want to make your function shorter: `function countE(str) { return str.match(/e/g).length; }`

Comment: @friedi, you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function countE(str) {
  if(typeof(str)==='undefined') str = 'eee';
  var count = 0;
  var charLength = str.length;

  for (i =0; i <= charLength; i++){
      if(str.charAt(i) == "e"){
          count++;
      }
  }
  console.log(count);
}
```

Comment: Now you can pass an argument or have the function assume 'eee' if no argument is given

Comment: You could also use the cleaner `str = str || "eee"` but I thought that the `if(typeof(str)==='undefined') str = 'eee';` was easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your function body shorter, you can do the following:

```
function countE(str) { 
    return str.match(/e/g).length; 
}
```

And even more sophisticated:

```
function count(what) {
    return function(str) {
        return str.match(new RegExp(what, 'g')).length;
    };
}

// now you can do the this
var countE = count('e');
var resultE = countE('excellent elephants');

var countL = count('l');
var resultL = countL('excellent elephants');
```

Comment: I think you are over-complicating things for a beginner with your delegates.

Comment: I want to give him some inspiration what is possible with javascript. I know it's too much for a beginner, but maybe in a few days/weeks he goes back here and then learns something new.

Comment: Fair enough, though it might be better with just another parameter. I don't see the point unless you are actually using the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your comment correctly, you want to do something like this:

```
function countE(inString) {
  var count = 0;
  var str = inString ? inString : "eee";
  var charLength = str.length;

  for (i =0; i <= charLength; i++){
      if(str.charAt(i) == "e"){
          count++;
      }
  }
   console.log(count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a regular expression

```
function countE(str) {
   var count = str.match(/e/g).length;
   console.log(count);
}
```

or

```
function countE(str) {
   console.log(str.match(/e/g).length);
}
```